# Typescript Doesn't Respect Lib

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, tsconfig

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "lib": ["ES5"],
      "strict": true,
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": ["./src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

`src/index.ts`:

```
  
console.log('Hello world');

Promise.all([]);

console.log([""].includes(""));

Promise.resolve().finally();

export function foo(): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.resolve(3.14);
  }

[""].find(() => true);
```

When I run `tsc` I would expect to get some type error about `Promise`, `Promise.finally`, `Array.find`, or `Array.includes` because I haven't specified those as being part of the `lib`. However, it actually compiles just fine. Why?

Comment: `Promise` and `Array` are native javascript classes (Promise if you are past a certain point of javascript version).  Why would it not compile?

Comment: More specifically, your node that executes the tslint logic is running at a certain javascript version.  That at a root level determines what methods are available, prior to importing polyfills.

Comment: Do you have `@types/node` installed? Depending on the version of `@types/node` and TypeScript you're using, `@types/node` might pull in the the definitions up to ES2018.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi yes it turns out I do have `@types/node` installed (i guess one of the modules in my package installed it) and when I delete it then I get errors upon running `tsc` as I expect. If you want to submit this as an answer I will accept it. However, I am still confused -- what am I supposed to do if I want `tsc` to give me an error when I try to use `Promise` e.g.. I want it to give me an error so that I know I need to polyfill it -- having `@types/node` doesn't polyfill `Promise` for me.

Comment: I think `@types/node` is assuming that you're code will be run by Node, which does provide a `Promise` implementation (going back a long time). If your code is not going to run in Node, then you end up with issues like this. :/ I'm not sure what is the "proper" solution here. I found the following comment on GitHub mentioning the exact same problem: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2142#issuecomment-469740262 and a relevant issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18588

Comment: You asked, *what am I supposed to do if I want tsc to give me an error when I try to use Promise*. One option for your situation is that, if you are not going to run on NodeJS, then do not include the `@types/node` package in `package.json`.